# javascript regex can not find and replace markdown codeblock correctly

Tags: javascript, regex

I have installed a `mermaid` plugin for `Gitbook` via [**gitbook-plugin-mermaid-gb3**](https://github.com/chriswessels/gitbook-plugin-mermaid-gb3), this plugin can parse code via markdown code block markup and translate it to a svg file, the code block is like below:

````markdown
```mermaid
graph TD;
  A-->B;
  A-->C;
  B-->D;
  C-->D;
```
````

But when I use it I found for some code it will not working, after check I found it was a bug inside the plugin.

The code is come from [**index.js**](https://github.com/chriswessels/gitbook-plugin-mermaid-gb3/blob/master/index.js) and related parse code listed below:

````
var mermaidRegex = /^```mermaid((.*[\r\n]+)+?)?```$/im;

function processMermaidBlockList(page) {

  var match;

  while ((match = mermaidRegex.exec(page.content))) {
    var rawBlock = match[0];
    var mermaidContent = match[1];
    page.content = page.content.replace(rawBlock, '<div class="mermaid">' +
      mermaidContent + '</div>');
  }

  return page;
}
````

The regex expression is ```` /^```mermaid((.*[\r\n]+)+?)?```$/im ````,but it can only find code bock starts with **```mermaid**,if there are space before or after it,it will not working

What I expected is like below

````
-- valid
```mermaid
graph TD;
  A-->B;
  A-->C;
  B-->D;
  C-->D;
```

-- valid, there can be space between ``` and mermaid
``` mermaid
graph TD;
  A-->B;
  A-->C;
  B-->D;
  C-->D;
```

-- valid, there can be space before or after ```
 ```mermaid
graph TD;
  A-->B;
  A-->C;
  B-->D;
  C-->D;
  ```
  
--invalid, there can not be have extra characters before ```
abc```mermaid
graph TD;
  A-->B;
  A-->C;
  B-->D;
  C-->D;
```  

--invalid, there can not be have extra characters before ```
abc ```mermaid
graph TD;
  A-->B;
  A-->C;
  B-->D;
  C-->D;
```  

--invalid, there can not be have extra characters before ```
abc ```mermaid
graph TD;
  A-->B;
  A-->C;
  B-->D;
  C-->D;
```  

--invalid, there can not be have extra characters after ```
```mermaid
graph TD;
  A-->B;
  A-->C;
  B-->D;
  C-->D;
```  abc

--invalid, there can not be have extra characters after mermaid
```mermaid abc
graph TD;
  A-->B;
  A-->C;
  B-->D;
  C-->D;
```
````

I changed ```` /^```mermaid((.*[\r\n]+)+?)?```$/im ```` to `https://regex101.com/r/CIrooL/1` and test it via [**https://regex101.com/r/CIrooL/1**](https://regex101.com/r/CIrooL/1),it seems okay,but not working inside javascript, I do not know why.

```
// this line will be blocked using the updated regex
while ((match = mermaidRegex.exec(page.content))) {
}
```

Can anyone help me,please?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you were trying [this (demo)](https://ideone.com/Rh7t98). But why not just do a global replacment with [capturing](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) using e.g. [this regex (regex101)](https://regex101.com/r/xl6Btj/1) instead of first extracting all those blocks? I mean [`page.content = page.content.replace(mermaidRegex, '<div class="mermaid">$1</div>');`](https://ideone.com/VOqG5g)

Comment: @bobblebubble Thanks for your reply,it almost works except one case **   ``` mermaid  aa** ,it will also replace this too,you can check it at  https://regex101.com/r/7K73Ha/1 ,however this is invalid, I would suggest you to post an anwser for it.

Comment: @Close voter,I have tried a lot,if you think it's  Not reproducible or was caused by a typoNot reproducible or was caused by a typo，please leave me a message,thank you

Comment: @bobblebubble I have fork your test code at https://ideone.com/Ro8wkF and it has show your the unexpected result

Comment: I see! Can we use negated backticks `[^\`]*` to match the stuff insides, or do you expect backticks inside as well? Please test if [this updated regex](https://regex101.com/r/7K73Ha/2) would work for you.

Comment: @bobblebubble I open your regex link and found it still match **``` mermaid  aa**,however it's an invalid format

Comment: Do you mean after `mermaid` the line can only contain spaces until the end, like in [this update](https://regex101.com/r/7K73Ha/3) or [that one](https://regex101.com/r/7K73Ha/4) which would also allow single backticks inside the block.

Comment: @bobblebubble seems both works fine,can you add an answer so that I can accept it,please?

Comment: Sure, give me some time, a bit busy. :) Great it's working now. Which one do you want, [the one that allows single backticks](https://regex101.com/r/7K73Ha/4) or  [this one not allowing any backticks](https://regex101.com/r/7K73Ha/3) in between?

Comment: @bobblebubble allow any space not backticks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255405/discussion-between-flyingfox-and-bobble-bubble).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of matching all those blocks and "raw" replacing each block an idea is to just do a *global* replacement. Also modify the regex to your needs [like this (regex101)](https://regex101.com/r/7K73Ha/4):

````
const mermaidRegex = /^[ \t]*```\s*mermaid[ \t]*$([^`]*(?:`[^`]+)*)```$/igm;
````

- The [global flag `g`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global?retiredLocale=de#description) is for replacing each occurance
- The [`m` multiline flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/multiline?retiredLocale=de#description) is for making `^` match *line*-start and `$` line-end
- `[ \t]*` will match [any amount](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of spaces or tabs
- `` ([^`]*(?:`[^`]+)*) `` [captures](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) the relevant part to the *first group*.
  The [negated class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) matches any character other than a backtick.
  To allow single occurances of backticks the repeated [group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) is used.

Finally change your function:

```
function processMermaidBlockList(page) {
  page.content = page.content.replace(mermaidRegex, '<div class="mermaid">$1</div>');
  return page;
}
```

[Here is a JS demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##lVFNa8MwDL37V4hQaJKtCbuNpulg5@2ya9NizXGNNycOthsGXX975nwMWhgts8FIen7Sk/SBLVpmZOMW7WPXpSkAYFmCkjVfWIfGAay/4fIcLAcBe4X@0QaE0u@owPBGIeMVr52nEKZr66DipkJZvnHBvyCHdLeBwm1jSmlh4wkcQ7Nws6PbOHxa0t64i@LI/5qlUlQZAbI/1MxJXUNjNOPWvo7cZ6XZ54u0LmxQ8AiOBKC3El/e9UryCzeZRIbnuu5hviplC0yhtXkwQcF69rBKfXw9j7wA3547mHrIlpETIS2awfEVjsGUPlgCLYb72zhx3DoyxnwXo/E35gd7lYt4A77BvwQB8T/1EempX8PV6WfD0rXiidIiPJ97lHXdDw) - `$1` in the replacement contains [what's captured](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) by the *first group*.

Comment: Could you improve it so that it also works with **         \`\`\`    mermaid **? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @flyingfox You mean [like this](https://regex101.com/r/DSD2pg/1)? If not, please update [the demo](https://regex101.com/r/DSD2pg/1) with some example.